# How to get canvas/ctx object in Chart.js for an Angular project

Tags: html, typescript, canvas, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to use Chart.js for my Angular application to build a line chart but I'm unable to correctly retrieve the canvas and ctx objects.

Here is my html:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

and here is my typescript code where I try to get the canvas and ctx:

```
    var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("myChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Apparently canvas isn't retrieved properly because I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
```

I'm currently using chart.js 2.7.2. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out for anyone interested. My issue was due to where I was trying to get the canvas. My canvas retrieval code was being done in my constructor. I moved it to an ngOnit() function and it worked fine.